# Django social auth GitHub authentication

Tags: python, django, github, django-socialauth

I'm new to Python and Django and am trying to get social auth (https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) to work. I'd like to connect using Github, but am not having much success and the example provided is a bit overwhelming to someone starting out.  Are there any recent tutorials available that explain how to use the latest version of social auth to setup GitHub authentication to a beginner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you read the documentation provided [here](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/github.html)

After installing the app, you need to do a bunch of configuration including specifying the `Github` [backend](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html)

You might also want to read up about the [OAuth Protocol](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-oauth-plus/wiki/Home) and what are all the tokens you need and how to obtain them.

If you need to access github specific API's only, I would encourage you to look into [PyGithub](https://github.com/jacquev6/PyGithub)

The authentication is as simple as doing `g = Github( token )` where token is from oauth.

Reading repos is as follows

```
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print repo.name
    repo.edit( has_wiki = False )
```

A related question to this is [Most suitable python library for Github API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625190/most-suitable-python-library-for-github-api-v3)

Comment: I finally got the authentication to work. Is there a way to get the logged in user's repos on Github from social_auth?