# Randomly sample Github repositories

Tags: python, github, random

I'm looking for a solution to randomly sample repos from Github. The final result is to perform some data analysis on the sample.

What I would like to do is sample by the repository's id: sample an int between 0 and 2.7 million and find the associated repo. After I have the username/repo-name, I'll use the api to get details.

The problem is I do not know how to search by repo id. Any suggestions? I'm open to webscraping or Python solutions.

Comment: not sure if it helps but you can access user by int id via the rest api. Then you can access any repository by that random user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python to access GitHUb V3 Api (as in "[Most suitable python library for Github API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625190/most-suitable-python-library-for-github-api-v3)").

And you can [access GitHub repos](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-repositories), from a certain id (`GET /repositories`, with as parameter,  integer ID of the last Repository that you’ve seen: so that can provide a roundabout way to access repos with their id.

Comment: I do not understand you solution, do you mind expanding it some more? In particular, what does "the last Repository that you’ve seen" mean?

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon It means it will list all repos starting the certain id. In your case, you can chose only the first one  as a way to access a repo per its id.

Comment: So for example, https://api.github.com/repositories?ID=50000 should return IDs >= 50000. But (at least for me), this url does not do that.

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon not `?ID=50000`, but `?since=50000`: then name of the parameter is '`since`'. See https://api.github.com/repositories?since=50000

Comment: Any way to find what the most recent ID is globally (to sample uniformly from all repositories)? Besides some kind of binary search?

Comment: @ondra.cifka 7+ years later, any search involving multiple repositories would be done by BigQueries (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bigquery-github/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) or possibly with the GraphQL GitHub API v4 (https://developer.github.com/v4/)